# AJAX/HTTP issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I have this code for a link that evaluates whether or not there are tags to determine what the link text should say:

```
<%= link_to "#{(@video.topics.count == 0) ? 'Add descriptive topics so people can find your song!' : 'Edit Topics'}", '#', :id => 'edit_topics_link', :class => 'edit' %>
```

The problem is that my tagging system updates completely with AJAX, and this link text does not, so it is only updated to the correct link text after a page refresh. How can I make the text update with AJAX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this easily using jQuery!

Just fetch the update data from the server (using $.get or $.post) and then update the link using the `text()` function. Here's an example:

```
$.get('http://some.url',{},function(response) {
  $('#edit_topics_link').text(response);
}
```

Pretty simple, isn't it?

Comment: yeah, I was actually just implementing this, but my question is what url should I be passing to the $.get() call? Should I make a new file and put my ruby link code in it?

Comment: @Justin: The URL should be whatever URL will return the updated text. That's up to you to decide what that would be.