# What url should i pass to the $.get() call?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, jquery

Check out the question I posed here: [AJAX/HTTP issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525580/ajax-http-issue)

I plan on using the suggestion from the first answer, but i have no clue what url I should be passing. Should I be making a new file, placing the ruby link code in that file, and just passing that file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [AJAX/HTTP issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525580/ajax-http-issue)

Comment: Referencing another question in a question isn't best SO practices. Please follow up on the comment thread for the first answer in the original question.

Comment: Well you have to have file on filesystem to whom you will be sending $.get/$.post request.
Personally i have one file (ajax.php in my case) that does all ajax work and answers all calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my understanding of the question is that you want to dynamically update a link's text?
If so, you need a script that can return the text the link should say.  Then call it with something like:

```
// linkid example: <a href="#" id="tt"></a> id is tt
function UpdateLink (linkid)
{
  $.get('script.php',{id: linkid},function(response) {
    $('#'+linkid).html(response);
  }
}
```

You would call the function, pass the link id (and the link id is passed with GET to the php/ruby script); then the link's text will be set to what the script returns.